# How to install every printer (with wildcard) from PrintServer

Tags: powershell, printer, wildcards

is there a quick and easy way to install every printer from a print server over a console like PowerShell?

Add-Printer from PowerShell does not support Wildcards.

I tried it with Get-Printer and ForEach

```
Get-Printer -ComputerName print-server | Select  name > Printers.txt

ForEach ($Printer in Get-Content "Printers.txt")
{
Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\print-server\"$Printer"
}
```

But I get only the message that the server name is not accessible or invalid. In the powershlel is to see that $Printer didn't replaced with the print name. But when I use Write-Host $Printer this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of piping the printers to a text file and then trying to use them by reading them back in as basic strings, use the properties of the objects returned from Get-Printer.

E.G.:

```
# Get list of printers from computer "print-server".
$Printers = Get-Printer -ComputerName print-server

# Iterate through the returned list of printers.
ForEach ($Printer in $Printers)
{
    # Check to see if the current printer is shared or not.
    If ($Printer.Shared) {
        # If it's shared, add it by using the print server name and printer name properties of the current printer object.
        Add-Printer -ConnectionName "\\$($Printer.ComputerName)\$($Printer.Name)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I execute this script, it never ends and the printer are not getting installed.

Comment: What you're saying about it running forever is hard to believe, unless there's some kind of transposition error, or some change you've made someplace. ;)   If you run just `$Printers = Get-Printer -ComputerName print-server` and then view `$Printers` is the list correct?

Comment: Yes the list is correct.

Comment: Did you launch the PowerShell prompt "As Administrator" before running the script?

Comment: Yes. I launched it "As Administrator". I guess on the print server are too many printers installed and this cause the problem?

Comment: @Roger How about opening PS as administrator, running `Get-Printer -ComputerName print-server` & then when you get that list, run each one-by-one to see if there's a specific printer that hoses it up from the list with the command:  `Add-Printer -ConnectionName "\\$($Printer.ComputerName)\$($Printer.Name)"` just use the values from the `Get-Printer -ComputerName print-server` command result list... Curious if there's one (or more) that causes a problem and this is why it's hosing up on you. e.g.permission issue, driver issue, etc. I've not tested any of it just adding common thing I'd try.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT Hi, thank your for you reply. I tested the PowerShell Script again and it works. Maybe I did something wrong before.

Answer (score 1):

For the script to function correctly a printer on the selected print server will need to have all the necessary permissions added. The printer in question (SelectPrinter) will be used in the script to pull security settings.

```
(Get-Printer 'SelectPrinter' Full).PermissionSDDL | Out-File 'C:\PrinterSecurity.txt' | $perms = Get-Content 'C:\PrinterSecurity.txt' | Set-Printer '*' -PermissionSDDL $perms.
```

This will add the permissions to all existing printers on the print server in question.

Run the command locally from the print server.